# Ansible vmware_guest runonce not being executed

Tags: ansible, vmware

I have the following tasks to deploy a Windows 2016 VM from template. All my customization is done correctly except the runonce command that is not executed. While running the playbook even in debug mode there is no error or warning.

```
- name: "[DEEPLOY-INSTANCE] Create a VM Win From a template"
  vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vmware.host }}"
        username: "{{ vmware.username }}"
        password: "{{ vmware.password }}"
        validate_certs: False
        datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
        cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        template: "{{ vm_template_full }}"
        folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
        datastore: "{{ vm_datastore }}"
        hardware:
          num_cpus: "{{ vm_cpu }}"
          memory_mb: "{{ vm_ram }}"
        networks: 
        - name: "{{ vm_netname }}"
          start_connected: yes
          ip: "{{ vm_ip }}"
          netmask: "{{ vm_mask }}"
          gateway: "{{ vm_gw }}"
          type: static  
        customization:
          fullname: "Windows Server"
          orgname: "My Company"
          timezone: 110
          dns_servers:
           - 10.100.100.10
           - 10.100.110.10
          domain: "{{ domain }}"
          joindomain: "{{ domain }}"
          password: "{{ template_pass }}"
          domainadmin: "{{ vmware.username }}"
          domainadminpassword: "{{ vmware.password }}"
          runonce:
          - 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Admin\Scripts\RunOnce.bat'
  register: vm_facts
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I tried putting the whole runonce command between single and double quotes but the output is the same. If I check the log C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\vmware-imc\guestcust.log there is no mention to even trying to attempt the execution of the runone but there is information about some customization being performed.

Ansible version is 2.9

**EDIT**

Changed indexation of runonce to how I have it now although it does not work either, with or without the quotes. As a workaround, I managed to launch that .bat file on a separate task with the module vmware_vm_shell

Answer (score 0):

Can you correct your indentation like below and try it once

```
runonce:
- powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Admin\Scripts\RunOnce.bat
```

Refer this issue:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28312

Comment: Usually Ansible accepts one or two spaces indistinctly for indexing. I did try indexing as you mentioned but the outcome was the same. On that link you shared the issue is that he had a colon followed by a space that I do not have.